# Stripe's JS not working with browser's Manual proxy configuration

Tags: proxy, stripe-payments, burp

I am trying to integrate stripe with my site. To detect security risks, I use Burp Suite. For that I have to modify my proxy settings.

I have set below proxy configurations in my Browser (Google Chrome)

```
HTTP proxy: 127.0.0.1
Port: 8000
```

Now when I fill the stripe form and try to purchase, I get below error

```
An unexpected error has occurred submitting your credit card to our secure 
credit card processor. This may be due to network connectivity issues, tt
so you should try again (you won't be charged twice). 
If this problem persists, please let us know!
```

This error is thrown by 
    https://js.stripe.com/v2/

Why do I get this error? I can't even open that URL in my browser. By the way I am able to open other sites like Google.

Answer (score 1):

You have an HTTP proxy, but you're trying to access an HTTPS site.